# Validación de campos PHP con notificación de campos en <li>

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo una validación de campos en PHP les dejo el código, este está en un archivo denominado "save_report.php"

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['save_report'])){
$cuenta = $_POST['cuenta'];
$number_report = $_POST['number_report'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

$alerts = array();

if($cuenta == ""){
    array_push($alerts, "Escribe el número de cuenta del reporte");
}

if($number_report == ""){
    array_push($alerts, "Escribe su número de reporte");
}

if($descripcion == ""){
    array_push($alerts, "Escribe la descripción del reporte");
}

/*AQUI ES LA DUDA*/

if(count($alerts) > 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($alerts); $i++)
    $_SESSION['message'] = <li> "$alerts[$i]" </li>;
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'warning';
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{

$query = "INSERT INTO task(cuenta, number_report, description) VALUES ('$cuenta', '$number_report', 
'$descripcion')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
if(!$resultado){
    die("Query Fallido: Reporte no salvaguardado");
}


$_SESSION['message'] = 'Reporte Salvaguardado';
$_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';

header("Location: index.php");
}
}
?>
```

Los campos son los siguientes

```
/*AQUI DEBE MOSTRARSE*/
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ ?>
<div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_type']; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<?= $_SESSION['message']?>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
<?php session_unset(); } ?>

<div class="card card-body">
    <form action="save_report.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="cuenta" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" 
            autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <input type="text" name="number_report" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de 
            Reporte" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <textarea name="descripcion" id="textarea_description" rows="10" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Descripción" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="save_report" value="Reportar" 
        style="margin-top:10px; width:100%;">
    </form>
```

Mi duda es como logra que notifique que campos le faltan, en base a los if validadores, quiero mostrarlo en lista

pero me marca error o me me dice que no se esperaba < . (Comente el código con /*AQUI ES LA DUDA*/)
Necesito que lo notifique por medio de SESSION en la parte de arriba esta esa parte (/*AQUI DEBE MOSTRARSE*/) solo me muestra "Escribe la descripción del reporte"
¿Cómo le hago?

Les dejo una screenshot
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué esto está mal `<li> "$alerts[$i]" </li>;` debería ser así `"<li>".$alerts[$i]."</li>";`

Comment: Pues lo acabo de colocar así como me indicas y si funciona pero no me marca los 3 en caso de que esten null, de hecho solo me notifica el de descripción lo lleno lo reporto pero ahora me dice que la cuenta y así, no me permite continuar con el else o notificarme los 3 al mismo tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

- Esta sintaxis para colocar cada mensaje de error es errónea:

  ```
  <li> "$alerts[$i]" </li>;
  ```
- Debería ser de esta forma:

  ```
  "<li>".$alerts[$i]."</li>";
  ```

Es decir debes encerrar entre comillas las etiquetas HTML ya que estás tratando de emplearlas en un archivo que contiene únicamente código PHP, (*sin embargo no considero adecuado el lugar donde tratas de iterar e imprimir la lista de errores*)

Considera esta propuesta:

- Si no viene vacío, entonces puedes almacenar directamente el array en la variable de sesión de esta forma:

  ```
  if (count($alerts) > 0) {
       $_SESSION['mensajes'] = $alerts;
  }
  ```

Ahora donde planeas mostrar estos valores (*es decir tu vista HTML*), puedes:

- Verificar si la variable de sesión no esta vacía y que si esté definida
- Iterar los valores del array que viajaron e imprimirlos en pantalla

  ```
  if (!empty($_SESSION['mensajes']) && isset($_SESSION['mensajes'])) {
      foreach ($_SESSION['mensajes'] as $alertaSesion) {
          echo "<li>".$alertaSesion."</li>";
      }
  }
  ```

**Comentarios extra**

- Deberías trabajar con [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), no es buena idea permitirle al usuario pasar de forma directa lo que te manda a la consulta
- **Únicamente para el proceso de depuración** no considero tal eficiente un *manejo de errores* como el siguiente pues no te dice realmente lo que puede estar mal:

  ```
   die("Query Fallido: Reporte no salvaguardado");
  ```
- Entonces (*para el punto anterior*) deberías revisar a profundidad el uso de *mysqli* que te provee de mejores [formas de llevarlo a cabo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)

**Propuesta de código**

//ARCHIVO 1

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if (isset($_POST['save_report'])) {

    $cuenta        = $_POST['cuenta'];
    $descripcion   = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $number_report = $_POST['number_report'];

    $alerts = array();

    if ($cuenta === "") {
        array_push($alerts, "Escribe el número de cuenta del reporte");
    }

    if ($number_report === "") {
        array_push($alerts, "Escribe su número de reporte");
    }

    if ($descripcion === "") {
        array_push($alerts, "Escribe la descripción del reporte");
    }


    if (count($alerts) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['mensajes'] = $alerts;
        $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'warning';
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {

        $query = "INSERT INTO task(cuenta, number_report, description) VALUES ('$cuenta', '$number_report', 
        '$descripcion')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

        if (!$resultado) {
            die("Query Fallido: Reporte no salvaguardado");
        }

            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Reporte Salvaguardado';
            $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';

            header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

//ARCHIVO 2

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_SESSION['mensajes']) && isset($_SESSION['mensajes'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['mensajes'] as $alertaSesion) {
            echo "<li>".$alertaSesion."</li>";
        }
    }
?>
.........................
.........................
.........................
```

Comment: Soy novato en desarrollos, tomare tu consejos...pero no entendi a lo que me dices lo siento

Comment: Realmente a casi nada, desde tu explicación de "<li>".$alerts[$i]."</li>";
Copie el codigo tratando de seguir lo que me explicaste y si me notifico los 3 nulls faltantes pero despues ya no ¿Serías tan amable de explicarme más detenidamente?

Comment: ¿Podrias códificarlo?
Si entiendo las cosas, pero no tan textualmente

Comment: @Minor elimino comentarios, edité mi respuesta espero te sea de ayuda, en caso contrario entonces esperemos los aportes de otros usuarios ;)